# Playframework 2.2 and Heroku: Unable to connect to non-Heroku database

Tags: mysql, heroku, playframework-2.2

I have my database hosted somewhere else and I have this in my /conf file:

```
db.default.driver= com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://myserver.com:3306/mydb"
db.default.user=myusername
db.default.password=mypassword
```

When I test it locally then it connects to the database just fine. I'm able to create/delete from the tables, etc. I changed the heroku config:

```
heroku config:add DATABASE_URL=mysql://myusername:mypassword@<myserver>:3306/mydb
```

and procfile

```
web: target/start -Dhttp.port=${PORT} ${JAVA_OPTS}
```

When I deploy it to heroku, I get errors:

```
2014-06-08T08:21:35.308207+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-06-08T08:21:35.309586+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2014-06-08T08:21:33.996174+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to    bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2014-06-08T08:21:33.996382+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2014-06-08T08:21:35.293114+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
```

The error log is pretty long. Please let me know if you need further information. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Are you overriding the database config in your `Procfile` in any way? Are there more errors than what you have listed? It looks like the connection might be hanging and causing the boot timeout, but it's really hard to tell based on that.

Answer (score 0):

This is a shot in the dark, as there isn't any indication of issue in the logs, but I've faced similar "ghost" failures with Heroku.

It seems that there is a very large latency trying to leave their network, for whatever reason.  While using an Apache Thrift RPC system on Heroku, nothing was working until I bumped the connection timeout to about 30 seconds.  I saw intermittent failures with RabbitMQ (the Heroku add-on version), and their support told me to bump the connection timeout in this case as well.

Based on that, I would add this to your config file:

```
db.default.connectionTimeout=30 seconds
```